# how I can read pointer data from boost::streambuf but without copy data

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I have a stream buffer I need send n data that I know exist(get it from writer)
I can use belo syntax:

```
streambuf b;
chat mybuf[1024]
std::istream is(&b);
is.read(mybuf,500);
```

In this way I copy data. I want only get pointer and avoid copy data. I want send like below:

```
asio::tcp::socket socket_;
socket_->send(
```

Is there a way to drive `streambuf` and use the protected `gptr` and `gbum, and is this a good way?

What do I need to do?

Comment: Why? If you read and write from a disk or a network connection, *that* is going to take a lot more time than copying 1024 chars.

Comment: It's hard to follow exactly what you're asking. But if you want to move pointers to data around, you don't want a stream to do it. You probably want a queue.

Comment: yes I am going to use boost:: socket_[socket_index]->send(

Comment: @BoPersson why this take more time than copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost::asio::streambuf` is no more than buffer queue. Use [`streambuf::data()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_streambuf/data.html). It return a list of buffer witch represents [committed](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_streambuf/commit.html) buffers. After successful send/write use [`streambuf::consume(size_t)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_streambuf/consume.html) to remove/reuse buffers.

```
streambuf b;
size_t size;
size= read( _socket, b.prepare( 1024 ) ); 
b.commit( size );   // after this function you may call read again
size= write( socket_, b.data() ); // you can check size() if there is anything
b.consume(size);  // remove size bytes from data() buffers
```